# PL-SQL - Extract query for all months

Tags: sql, oracle

I stucked on something. I have duties table and there are duties scheduled every month. So there is date column. I want to get **duty count for per month.** Here is my extract query and result view:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DUTY_DATE) "Month", COUNT(*) "Count" 
 FROM DUTY_DATES WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DUTY_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) 
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DUTY_DATE) ORDER BY "Month" ASC;
```

[image: result view]

But problem is; i can't get row if there is no duty in some month. For ex, you can see there is no Jan row because there is no duty which scheduled at jan. But i want to get it with count:0 column. **So my goal in short:** Getting count for every mont in year. My result table must has 12 row every time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a table containing all the months and then use your table in outer join:

```
SELECT all_months.month "Month", COUNT(DUTY_DATES.DUTY_DATE) "Count"
FROM (    SELECT LEVEL AS month
            FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) all_months
     LEFT OUTER JOIN DUTY_DATES
         ON (    all_months.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DUTY_DATE)
             AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DUTY_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE))
GROUP BY all_months.month
ORDER BY "Month" ASC;
```

For example, with a test case like the following

```
CREATE TABLE DUTY_DATES (duty_date) AS
    (SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' FROM DUAL)
```

your query would give

```
     Month      Count
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
```

while what I suggested will give:

```
     Month      Count
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          0
         4          0
         5          0
         6          0
         7          0
         8          0
         9          0
        10          0
        11          0
        12          0

12 rows selected.
```

Comment: Oh all_months, haven't heard. Ok it looks good but there is a problem, my first row is: 1-1 but there is no duty scheduled in jan 2017. I checked it out twice. Might be some issue about something? I'm confused.

Comment: That sounds strange. Can you please build a test case to check this behaviour?

Comment: I've builded one like yours and it works good. I don't know what happens about my original table but i think i should work on it. Your solution works perfect and it is the answer of this question,thank you :)